# Ajax request error on Node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, cookies

I have a `node.js` server running on port `3000` and in my `index.html` file on that server, I send a `Ajax` request to `apache2 server` on port `80` to retrieve the current cookie on the site. However, I get no cookie response even though I see the cookie on my browser. My `Ajax` request on `index.html`:

```
$.ajax ({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://103.57.220.117:80/chatroom/api/auth",
        async: false,
        global: false,
        processData: false,
        contenType: "application/json",
        data: "",
        success: function(r) {
            console.log(r)
        },
        error: function(r) {
            console.log(r)
        }
});
```

In my `index.php` endpoint on my api file:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {

if ($_GET['url'] == 'auth') {

    $cookie= $_COOKIE['SNID'];
    echo '{ "cookie" : '.$cookie.' }';
    http_response_code(200);

}

}
```

The api response with the 200 code but [no cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSQAg.png)

However, on the browser there is cookie displayed and active ([cookie on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lUV8.png))

Is there any way to fix this? I really need solution because this is very important for my school project

Comment: What does the code look like that deploys your server?  That could be a large reason why your not seeing a cookie.  Whats your app.js file look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies can not be shared across sites, this includes sites on the same domain but using different ports.